# Stock management tool or excel spreadsheet for managing stock

Tags: microsoft-excel, finance

What is the best or recommended free/opensource tool for managing stocks and shares. It should include at least the following

- List of shares i have bough
- List of shares i have sold
- Total capital
- Profit and loss (for those that i have sold)
- Graphs of prices over time.
- Current price of current holdings and possibly show the estimated profit if i were to sell.
- some fancy graphs maybe?

Any tool like that out there or am i asking for too much? :)

Just out of curiosity, The above might be possible using an excel spreadsheet. Does one exist somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Google Finance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Variant suggested, Google Finance, Yahoo Finance, AOL Finance - most of these perform exactly what you're talking about to some degree. ALL trading firms (eTrade, Ameritrade, etc.) will provide more advanced tools to handle.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but the real question is 'should it be done'? I'm a self-proclaimed Excel geek and have been known to program in the ability to retrieve live stock information into spreadsheets. but for what you are looking for Google Finance, or an equivalent will be a much better solution.

Comment: The problem with google finance is you have to have an internet connection everytime you want to look at your portfolio. I would like to be able to see the portfolio even if im not connected to the internet.